# vis.js progress bar does not show correct value

Tags: css, vis.js

I am trying to implement the progress bar right now, but the progressbar does not show the value which i would recommend. The progress bar shows always around 55% doesnt matter how the value is set.

```
  var items = new vis.DataSet([
{id: 0, group: 0, content: 'item 0',value: 0.0, start: new Date(2014, 3, 17), end: new Date(2014, 3, 21)},
{id: 1, group: 0, content: 'item 1',value: 0.2, start: new Date(2014, 3, 19), end: new Date(2014, 3, 20)},
{id: 2, group: 1, content: 'item 2',value: 0.3, start: new Date(2014, 3, 16), end: new Date(2014, 3, 24)},
{id: 3, group: 1, content: 'item 3',value: 0.4, start: new Date(2014, 3, 23), end: new Date(2014, 3, 24)},
{id: 4, group: 1, content: 'item 4',value: 0.65, start: new Date(2014, 3, 22), end: new Date(2014, 3, 26)},
{id: 5, group: 2, content: 'item 5',value: 0.8, start: new Date(2014, 3, 24), end: new Date(2014, 3, 27)}
```

]);

```
.progress-wrapper {
  background: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.progress {
  height: 100%;
  width: 60%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  background: #63ed63;
}

.progress-label {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

[Here is my jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaliph/w7oyxk0a/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shows 60% of the width because that is what you are specifying:

```
.progress {
  width: 60%;
}
```

If you want it to match the percentage in the label, then you have to specify that in the HTML you are returning from your template:

```
visibleFrameTemplate: function(item) {
  if (item.visibleFramTemplate) {
    return item.visibleFramTemplate;
  }
  var percentage = item.value * 100 + '%';
  return '<div class="progress-wrapper"><div class="progress" style="width:' + percentage + '"></div><label class="progress-label">' + percentage + '<label></div>';
}
```

The relevant part is where the style is set for the width: `style="width:' + percentage + '"`.

I would concede that the example in the vis.js docs does what you've done - its not a particularly clear example of what to do. Raised a bug to fix that at https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/2827